# Button click listener in xml

Tags: android, xml

For button click listeners code runs fine when click listeners are defined in the activity but facing problem when defining click listener in the xml, no spelling mismatch

following error on logcat appears when listener are defined in xml, why?

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method addButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'addButton'

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:onClick="addButtonClicked"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputField"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputField"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/inputField" />
```

This is Activity Class

When click listener is defined in xml

```
public void addButtonClicked()
{

     String text = inputField.getText().toString();
     Products p = new Products(text);
     dbObj.addProduct(p);
     printDatabase();

}
```

When click listener is defined from Activity, This works fine

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String text = inputField.getText().toString();
            Products p = new Products(text);
            dbObj.addProduct(p);
            printDatabase();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your activity class with button click code

Comment: You not declare addButtonClicked method in activity file

Comment: I got it, the parameter View was missing, thanks Nir Duan and IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to you activity:

```
    public void addButtonClicked(View view) {
     //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Could not find method addButtonClicked(View)

**addButtonClicked() method Missing .**

Create `addButtonClicked()` method first  .

```
 public void addButtonClicked(View v)
{ 
   // Add your Staff here
}
```

**`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .